# Run a Cakefile Programmatically

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, cakephp

I spent a lot of time building this wonderful Cakefile in Coffeescript that builds everything, and now I'd like to be able to run the command `cake build` from outside of that directory using another alias thats relevant to my program.

Is there any way to run `cake build` from within a executable file? Something I can have executed by npm under '/bin'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's no command line option to do that

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/lib/cake.js#L38

```
  exports.run = function() {
    return path.exists('Cakefile', function(exists) {
      var arg, args, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
      if (!exists) {
        throw new Error("Cakefile not found in " + (process.cwd()));
      }
```

So your process will probably need to 'cd' to the directory of your Cakefile first, in order to run it.   (Or you can patch coffescript to take an argument)

Answer (score 4):

As Noli says, the only way to do it is to either reverse-engineer `cake.js` or—more simply—run the `cake` command from the target directory. Under Node, you can do that using [child_process.spawn](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4/api/child_processes.html#child_process.spawn) by setting the `cwd` option to the desired working directory.